# Add status icons over file icons in Explorer, like Dropbox or SVN in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, icons, overlay

I'm writing a Windows service application in C# with `FileSystemWatcher`.

How can I add status icons to files and folders in Windows Explorer similar to how Dropbox or SVN do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should develop an overlay icon handler and register it into the system.
[Here](http://www.mombu.com/programming/c/t-c-shell-extension-handler-icon-overlay-handler-1568092.html) you can find a partially working example written in C#.
Some MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127442(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I searched with Google all morning. It turned out that I just do not know how it correctly called. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I just found, that you must not write Shell Extension on .Net: [that's why](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/1428326d-7950-42b4-ad94-8e962124043e/). But you can write it on C++ or something unmanaged and use it as a module in your .net program.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still interessted in this question:

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545781/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Handlers) is a codeproject link which describes the process in great detail.

It uses the [SharpShell](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell) library, which can also be found on nuget.

Code, from the codeproject, looks something like that:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ReadOnlyFileIconOverlayHandler : SharpIconOverlayHandler
{
  protected override int GetPriority()
  {
    //  The read only icon overlay is very low priority.
    return 90;
  }

  protected override bool CanShowOverlay(string path, FILE_ATTRIBUTE attributes)
  {
    try
    {
      //  Get the file attributes.
      var fileAttributes = new FileInfo(path);

      //  Return true if the file is read only, meaning we'll show the overlay.
      return fileAttributes.IsReadOnly;
    }
    catch (Exception) { return false; }
  }

  protected override System.Drawing.Icon GetOverlayIcon()
  {
    //  Return the read only icon.
    return Properties.Resources.ReadOnly;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup - I maintain the SharpShell library and this is a perfectly valid way to create a Shell Icon Overlay Handler.

Answer (score 2):

I've never play with this, but I think it's the right way.

[Custom Folder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/CustomizingFolders.aspx)

First make the folder a System Folder, then create a Desktop.ini file and apply the change inside.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=@Shell32.dll,-12690
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll
IconIndex=-238
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want. First Answer is the right one.