# Add small icon to any file/folder`s icon in windows using java or other programming languaga

Tags: c#, java, c, windows

We are developing an small windows application for doc syncing from server to desktop specific folder. So i need a method like in dropbox to add a small processing/completed icon to file/folder which are processing. And if i move that file outside the main folder that icon should be disappear.

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: `JFrame#setIconImage` is what you are looking at ?

Comment: Please visit this thread!
This can help on your problem too :)
[Add status icon][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383668/add-status-icons-over-file-icons-in-explorer-like-dropbox-or-svn-in-net

Comment: @Krekkon `TrayIcon` may  help ?

Comment: I am not asking icon on frame, i want to add icon on file in filesystem window, as dropbox do

Comment: Windows/Internet Explorer have an extension mechanism known as Browser Helper Objects (BHOs). You would need to implement one to do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions

Comment: Like @Krekkon suggest, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383668/add-status-icons-over-file-icons-in-explorer-like-dropbox-or-svn-in-net

Answer (score 0):

The following article describes how to implement icon overlay handlers using the Windows C API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127442(v=vs.85).aspx

The whole section might be interesetting to read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521690(v=vs.85).aspx