# Small Icon on folders like Dropbox

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I add a small icon on folders using vb.net?
Just like [image: this]

I don't know the right term for this, that's I always end up searching on a dead end.
Any ideas?

Comment: do you want to add a icon to your exsisting app in vb.net?

Comment: I think its not a icon on a folder icon, the whole thing is an icon in itself

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259673

Comment: i think you are referring to the tick mark right?

Comment: I have browsed the folder properties, under customize, I noticed that the icon doesn't have the little checkmark. I guess it means that it's not an icon itself.. It is somehow added on the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for something like "*windows explorer icon overlay*", some results :

- [Add status icons over file icons in Explorer, like Dropbox or SVN in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383668/add-status-icons-over-file-icons-in-explorer-like-dropbox-or-svn-in-net)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang
- This is my personal favorite : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545781/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Handlers

Comment: Thanks for this har07. This will get me started :)